# Comparing equality of 2 ArrayList<int[]> with equals()

Tags: java, android, arraylist, comparison, equals

I have two ArrayLists which are `ArrayList<int[]>`.  I want to see if they are identical.  By identical I mean the same length, same content and in the same order.  I am comparing the ArrayLists as so:

```
public boolean isWon() {

    if(getAllBtnCoords().equals(getAllTVCoords())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU WON!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT YET...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have even gone so far as create an `ArrayList<int[]>`, then create a new variable and just set it equal to the already created `ArrayList<int[]>` so that I am 100% sure they are the same.  I then run the `isWon()` method and it always returns false.

What am I doing incorrectly?  Am I using the wrong function of `equals()` to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On quick solution would be:

- Define your own comparison method whi which takes the to ArrayList as inputs
- Check none of them is null
- Check both have the same size
- One by one take the two arrays
- Check these to have the same length
- Then iterates through all of them and check to be equal
- If any of the previous is not true, return false, otherwise you got a match

Something like:

```
private boolean areArrayEqual(ArrayList<int[]> a, ArrayList<int[]> b) {
    if (a == null) return false;
    if (b == null) return false;
    if (a.size() != b.size()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        int x[] = a.get(i);
        int y[] = b.get(i);
        if (x.length != y.length) return false;
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (x[j] != y[j]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When I saw all the other answers told me that the route I was taking was not correct and that I would have to create my own compare method, I was dreading it.  Thank you for providing in your answer also the way to compare the 2 `ArrayLists<int>`!

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList<int[]>` is a list of arrays of integers.  So it looks like you're trying to compare a two-dimensional array, more or less.  When you use `equals` on an `ArrayList` or any other `List`, it compares each element of the `List` using the `equals` function of the element type.

The problem is that arrays such as `int[]` don't have a special `equals` function.  Arrays are objects, and the default `equals` for objects compares the **references** to see if they're equal.  So using `.equals` on the `ArrayList` will return `true` if the elements of the `ArrayList`, which are `int[]`, are all the same reference.  It will not check the elements of the `int[]` arrays.

Either you'll need to do this yourself with a loop; or make your type an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, which would make `equals` work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in that the equals method for arrays is basically not implemented, it only matches on object equality. So as long as the coordinate arrays in the two lists are not the exact same objects it will return false.

For example, this piece of code prints false:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2};
    int[] b = {1, 2};
    System.err.println(a.equals(b));
}
```

I would advise you to replace the usage of int arrays by Point or Coordinate objects with a properly implemented equals (and hashcode) function. (Perhaps a [lombok](http://projectlombok.org) @Data object!).

Answer (score 1):

Equals in `ArrayList` internally call equals on its elements. Int array implementation is just comparing references which are not same so the correct comparing function would be.

```
public static boolean intArraysEquals(List<int[]> listOne, List<int[]> listTwo)
{
    if(listOne.size() != listTwo.size())
        return false;

    for(int i = 0, size = listOne.size(); i < size; i++)
    {
        int[] firstArray = listOne.get(i);
        int[] secondArray = listTwo.get(i);

        if(!Arrays.equals(firstArray, secondArray))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

than your `isWon()` function could look like

```
public boolean isWon() {

    if(intArraysEquals(getAllBtnCoords(), getAllTVCoords())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU WON!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT YET...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```