# Check if ArrayList<int[]> Contains same array order ignored

Tags: java, arraylist

I've initialized an ArrayList holding int arrays as such:

`ArrayList<int[]> holder = new ArrayList<int[]>();`

If I add an int[] like this:

`int[] first = {1, 2, 3};`

`holder.add(first);`

If I do this check, I want the function to return true, but it returns false right now

`int[] second = {2, 1, 3};`

`if(holder.contains(second)) return true;`

`else return false`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616242/comparing-equality-of-2-arraylistint-with-equals

Comment: @zysaaa That question is comparing two arrayList<int[]>, while im trying to check if an int[] is contained in the arrayList<int[]> ignoring the order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use `ArrayList#Contains` to judge since `int[]` don't have a special `equals`.  You can iterate list and then compare:

```
    private static boolean contains(ArrayList<int[]> holder, int[] arr) {
        for (int[] item : holder) {
            if (equals(item, arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154305/java-checking-equality-of-arrays-order-doesnt-matter
    private static boolean equals(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] copyOfArr1 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
        int[] copyOfArr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr2, arr2.length);
        Arrays.sort(copyOfArr1);
        Arrays.sort(copyOfArr2);
        return Arrays.equals(copyOfArr1, copyOfArr2);
    }
```

Comment: Bad answer. It mutates the arrays as a side effect fever of calling `equals()`, and all unexpected/unadvertised side effect are very bad. Might as well just sort all the array's first, then use plain `contains()`